# Rails 4 - Simple Form - how to get rid of the label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, simple-form

I'm trying to figure out how to use simple form without the pre-determined label.

I've tried setting label to false as set out below, but it doesn't stop the label of the attribute ('trl') from appearing beside the collection.

```
<%= f.input :trl do %>
    <%= f.select :trl, Trl.all.map { |t| [t.title, t.id] }, label: false,  include_blank: false, prompt: 'Select one' %>
    <% end %>
```

Is there a way to dis-apply the labels in simple form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= f.input :trl, label: false do %>
  <%= f.select :trl, Trl.all.map { |t| [t.title, t.id] },include_blank: false, prompt: 'Select one' %>
<% end %>
```